# With angular-cli why do I have to add all app folders to app specific barrels?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, systemjs

The relevant part of my system-config.js looks like this

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  ...

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/i18n',
  'app/main',
  'app/pages/home',
  'app/pages/resolution',
  'app/store',
  'services'

  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

I tried including index.ts files deeper down in the folder tree in my app/index.ts. That did not work. Although if it would work, this whole App specific barrel part would be unnecessary, and

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  ...

  // App specific barrels.
  'app'
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

Would be enough.

Is there maybe a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In angular-cli, when you do any `ng generate controller c_name` it automatically adds  your controller in to `system-config.ts` barrels. So I think, there is no way what you are asking for. If you remove any of the barrels thing, it will give you error.

Answer (score 0):

You can update angular-cli to **1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2**

Here is the [**link**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md) to manual.